# django - how to display list objects from model in 'base.html' and extends it to all other templates

Tags: python, django

I have a navbar in "base.html" and i want to list objects from model on it,
so this list be visible on all other template that extends 'base.html'

'base.html'

```
<nav>
   {% for category in categories %}
      <a href="#">{{ category.category_name }}</a>
   {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

models.py

```
class Categories(models.Model):
   category_name           = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

views.py

```
class NavbarView(ListView):
   model               = Categories
   template_name       = 'base.html'
   context_object_name = 'categories'
```

urls.py

```
path('nav/', views.NavbarView.as_view(), name='nav')
```

this makes categories list visible only on 'nav/' urls but not in all templates that extends 'base.html

how can i do this ? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use context processors for this.
For example if you want categories to be dynamic in all your template:

context_processors.py

```
def categories(request):
    categories = Categories.objects.all()
    return {"categories": categories}
```

And add this context_processor in your settings.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ......................,
                'your_app.context_processors.categories', # path to your context_processor
            ],
```

Comment: Do i need to add url for this view ?

Comment: @Progam No you don't need. You just need to provide the path for your custom processors inside your settings.

Answer (score 2):

One option to give you a bit more flexibility is to create a mixin:

```py
class NavMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NavMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Categories.objects.all()
        return context
```

You can include it in your class based views like this:

```py
class MyListView(NavMixin, ListView):
    ...
```