# How to get the user details of the logged-in user in every view function in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates

For my project, I use build-in user authentication of django. Then using that details I query a custom table to get additional details pertaining to that user.  Actually, I need this user details in every view function in the project as these details are then carried forward through context variable to every template in the project. This is for setting the menu bar of the website using these user details accordingly.

Now the thing is .. I have written a function named 'logged_user_details' for populating these details in to a context variable in that function, which is then passed to every other view functions in which it is called. Then this context variable is then appended with the context variable of that view function and forwarded to template.

Somewhere..I think it is not suppose to be like this. The point is I need to call this function in every view function written in the project and then append context variable of this custom function  with the context variable of that view function. I am new to django, Please help me. Thank You..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288811/12061653 i hope this will help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provide extra context to all views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533854/provide-extra-context-to-all-views)

Comment: Thank you Arjun and Abdul. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SankarNarayanan if the answer helped you then please upvote the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive those things using decorators.

## signals.py

```py
from functools import wraps

def get_user(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        # Check if the user is authenticated
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user = request.user
            # Add the user key to the context
            context['user_obj'] = user
        # Call the view function with the updated context
        return func(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

## views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .decorators import get_user

@get_user
def your_view(request, context):
  # Your view logic using the context
  context['name'] = 'shubham'
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mahammadhusain for your reply. I think as per my requirement context processor is mush suited, because in decorator function I would have to manually add it again all the views in the project. Thanks for your help.